# Adding widgets to my plugin page instead of WordPress dashboard

Tags: php, plugin-development, widgets, hooks, actions

So below is the action to add widget in the WordPress dashboard. How can i add widgets in my plugin's page?

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'csc412_dashboard_widgets');

    function csc412_dashboard_widgets() {
        global $wp_meta_boxes;

        wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Good morning', 'custom_dashboard_help');
    }
    function custom_dashboard_help() {

        global $current_user;
        $username = $current_user->user_login;

        echo 'Greetings, '.$username.'. Today is ' . Date('m/d/Y');
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean giving your plugin a settings page? If so: https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Comment: no no.  This function adds widget to the WordPress dashboard. I want make that widget to appear to a custom page of my preference instead of the WordPress dashboard

Comment: Then I think you're looking in the wrong place. It's the Settings API you want for that.